# WHERE id_member = 1 doesn't work in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Well I have that code:

```
$query="INSERT INTO ".$db_prefix."members (badges) VALUES ('$id_badge') WHERE id_member = '$user_id'";
```

And PHP drop me that error:

**Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id_member = '1'' at line 1**

What can I do? :/

---

### SORRY FOR EVERY PERSON WHO HAS REPLY TO ME I WAS WORNG WITH THE $QUERY, I HAVE EDITED TO THE CORRECT QUERY, NOW YOU CAN ANSWER ME. THANKS. :D

---

### To every person that have voted me down, I'm starting in mysql... ¬¬

Comment: We didnt use WHERE condition while INSERT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `WHERE` in `INSERT INTO`. Use `UPDATE` command:

```
$query = "UPDATE " . $db_prefix . "members SET badges = '" . $id_badge . "' WHERE id_member = '" . $user_id . "'";
```

Comment: Sorry I has made an edit to the code... I wasn't the first query was the second...

Comment: Thanks! The first person who ans me how to use correctly db_prefix, I will mark it as solved. (Sorry for bad english, I'm spanish)...

Comment: I have solved it, but I will put you the mark, cuz @gautam is afk.

Comment: One question, Can I serialize with SET? Because, it drop me an error...

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET badges = 'a:1:{s:7:"user_id";s:1:"1";}' WHERE id_member = 1' at line 1

Comment: are you sure if `a:1:{s:7:"user_id";s:1:"1";}` is correct value?

Comment: In UPDATE command you need to use command SET to set new values.

Comment: So? I don't know what you mean... Sorry... I know that, it works as you say, but I have a question, Its overwrites something, or only write a new serialized value? :P

Comment: It ovewrites value badges if id = (member id). If id is not equal to member_id, nothing happens.

Comment: I think that I'm doing is more or less, I think that WHERE only sets where the value is going to go, not?

Comment: WHERE sets, which row(s) will be changed in UPDATE command.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp, 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm

Comment: I don't know why the error drops, If the WHERE is correct, the only thing that cannot be correct is the value, and it is not logic...

Comment: Maybe column **badge_id** is an integer and I am not sure if `a:1:{s:7:"user_id";s:1:"1";}` is integer

Comment: You want the table of my db?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like

```
$query="UPDATE ".$db_prefix."members SET badges = '$id_badge' WHERE id_member =  '$user_id'";
```

You need to `UPDATE` the table not INSERT.And Try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to the entire `ext/mysql PHP` extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_*`, is officially deprecated as of `PHP v5.5.0` and will be **removed in the future**.

There are two other `MySQL` extensions that you can better Use: `MySQLi` and `PDO_MySQL`, either of which can be used instead of `ext/mysql`.

Comment: what is $db_prefix echoing..??

Comment: smf_ikill, but the error is in WHERE id_member (if a put smf_ikillmembers, the error doesn't dissapears)

Comment: Sorry I has made an edit to the code... I wasn't the first query was the second...

Comment: And, why I will want to update it, if I have to put a new value? :/

Comment: We didnt have WHERE with INSERT.

Comment: Thanks! The first person who ans me how to use correctly db_prefix, I will mark it as solved. (Sorry for bad english, I'm spanish)...

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong do not insert data just update it

```
@mysql_query("UPDATE ".$db_prefix."members SET badges = '".$id_badge."' WHERE member_id='".$user_id."'");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "UPDATE '".$db_prefix."members'
     SET badges=$id_badge
     WHERE id_member =".$user_id;
```

Comment: I have edited my answer according to the new quesion.Because When I have given the answer of first question then first question was changed.Then I edited the new answer according to new question.The person has changed the questions.

Answer (score -2):

try putting up below line:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `badges` FROM ".$db_prefix." members WHERE `id_member` = ".(int)$id_del_usuario."");
```

your second query:

```
$query="INSERT INTO ".$db_prefix."members SET (badges) VALUES (".$id_badge.") WHERE `id_member` = ".$user_id."";
```

Comment: Do you know, what did you write?
FROM ".$db_prefix." `members`

Comment: Sorry I has made an edit to the code... I wasn't the first query was the second...

Comment: Why? If you can explain to me, I will be very grateful... :P

Comment: It was meaned to @Jay